# How to wrap text using simple_list_item_multiple_choice?

Tags: android, textview, listactivity, word-wrap, android-wrap-content

I'm using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to display a single `CheckedTextView`. I know this is done best using `simple_list_item_multiple_choice` and `android.R.id.text1`.

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, rules, 
              new String[]{Constants.KEY_RULE}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
```

If the text from `KEY_RULE` is more than two lines, android doesn't wrap, instead it hides it. Is there an easy work-around for this without having to implement my own adapter?

Find my xml code below:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/header" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/rule_selection_for_revision_list_title"
        android:padding="4dip" android:background="#000000" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textStyle="bold" />

  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />

    <TextView android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@id/android:empty" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="There are no rules to consider." />

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any way I can at least reduce the font size so that it fits to two lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options.

You can define your custom layout for item in the list. This allows you to fully customize your item UI. More details can be found in [List View tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).

The other approach can be used if you still want to use standard item layout but only fix one **small** thing in it. You can extend Adapter and modify the view in `getView` function. Here is an example:

```
class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
    public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context ctx, int layout, 
                                 Cursor cursor, String [] from, int [] to)
    {
        super(ctx, layout, cursor, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        //You can increase number of lines in the text view
        textView.setMaxLines(5);

        LayoutParams params = textView.getLayoutParams();
        if(params.height > 0)
        {
            int height = params.height;
            params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;                              
            textView.setLayoutParams(params);
            textView.setMinHeight(height);
        }

        //Or you can make your font smaller
        textView.setTextSize(customTextSize);

        //or whatever you like, even apply new custom style
        //...

        return view;
    }   

}
```

You should probably choose the first approach (custom layout), but sometimes the second approach is feasible too.

Comment: the second approach suits me better I think. The only problem is that MaxLines doesn't work. setTextSize works though but is less of a neat solution. Isn't there any way you can tell the text view to wrap its contents and increase automatically rather than having a static height?

Comment: `setMaxLines(N)` is supposed to do exactly this. It will increase `TextView` size up to N lines. There layout were `TextView` is located might restrict the height also. Let me check.

Comment: Ok, if you look at http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml&q=layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc, you'll notice the android:layout_height is set to specific height (using current theme value). This can be overriden in your code. I've update answer to show how to set the height of `TextView`.

Comment: I get a ClassCastException on ViewGroup.LayoutParams.

Comment: I've updated the code. I can't run and check the code right now, so it might not work correctly :) But you should get the idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement a custom Adapter. Just define a custom layout for the list items and pass it to the adapter instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`.

You can search the Android sources (come with the SDK on you computer) to how the original simple_list_item_multiple_choice layout looks like and adapt it to your needs.